# How to put a function in a for loop and wait for user input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a simple quiz where two terms are displayed in different languages (I have used numbers here to avoid confusion). 50% of the time the terms will match. The user has the option of choosing yes or no for whether the terms match or not. The questions are displayed in random order and it doesnt matter if they repeat.

The idea is that this should be repeated multiple times.

I can't seem to get the loop to work, at the moment it runs through and prints all the questions out at the start. I would like it to print out a new question when the user clicks.

Here is a link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sX8Rz/1/

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var score = 0;

var hiraganaWords1 = [
    ["1", "one"],
    ["2", "two"],
    ["3", "three"],
    ["4", "four"],
    ["5", "five"],
    ["6", "six"],
    ["7", "seven"],
    ["8", "eight"],
    ["9", "nine"],
    ["10", "ten"]
];


    function askQuestion() {
        var questionNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * hiraganaWords1.length));
        var trueFalse = Math.round(Math.random());
        var wrongAnswer = Math.floor((Math.random() * hiraganaWords1.length));
        var correct = hiraganaWords1[questionNumber][0];
        var trueAnswer = hiraganaWords1[questionNumber][1];
        var incorrectAnswer = hiraganaWords1[wrongAnswer][1];

        if (trueFalse === 0) {
            $("#japanese").append(correct);
            $("#english").append(trueAnswer);
            var answer = "yes";
            $("#yes").click(function () {
                var guess = "yes";
                if (guess === answer) {
                    score++;
                    alert("well done your score is: " + score);

                } else {
                    score = 0;
                    alert("try again");
                }

            });
            $("#no").click(function () {
                var guess = "no";
                if (guess == answer) {
                    score++;
                    alert("well done your score is: " + score);
                    $("#japanese").html(" ");
                    $("#english").html(" ");
                } else {
                    score = 0;
                    alert("try again" );


                }
            })

        } else {
            $("#japanese").append(correct);
            $("#english").append(incorrectAnswer);
            var answer = "no";
            $("#yes").click(function () {
                var guess = "yes";
                if (guess == answer) {
                    score++;
                    alert("well done" + score);

                } else {
                    score = 0;
                    alert("try again" + score);
                }

            });
            $("#no").click(function () {
                var guess = "no"
                if (guess == answer) {
                    score++;
                    alert("well done" + score);
                } else {
                    score = 0;
                    alert("try again" + score);


                }
            })

        }



    }

 for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    askQuestion();
 }


});
```

Thanks in advance and I am sorry for the noob question, I am just learning and would appreciate the help.

Cheers
Andy

Comment: IMHO, a loop is the wrong way to do this. Use a variable to keep track of which question you are on and advance it after the user has selected an answer. Also, each time you call `askQuestion` you are attaching *another* event handler to each of those elements. They will all execute, so by question 5 you will be executing 5 click handlers on `#yes`

Comment: Also, you'll want to think about your logic some more. You have nothing to prevent it from asking the same question twice and you don't appear to have anything to check if the "wrong" answer is actually the same as the "right" answer.

Comment: Thank you for input. Yes I see now that the loop is the wrong way to do it. I have been a bit busy at work but think I have almost cracked it and will post again when I do.

Answer (score 3):

You can't wait in JavaScript (and if you could, the browser would block and clicking anywhere wouldn't have any effect).

So the solution is to ask the next question when the user has clicked on her choice (after you display the result for the last question).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you trying to solve data binding problem with wrong approach. I recommend you to look on [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) or [Knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) for solution of your problem (building dynamic user responsive javascript interface). It may save you some time.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to understand from your code a bit. But I can give a general idea.

Implement a function called `askQuestion` like:

```
// add more questions
var questions = ["Eaten food?", "Exercised?"];

// add more choices of your own
var choices = [
    ["one", "four", "three", "two"],
    ["onasde", "foadur", "thradasdee", "two00"], ];

$(document).ready(function () {
    askQuestion(0);    
});
function askQuestion (index){ 
    // where index is the index of question in questions array and choices in choices array
    // display question and choices
    $("#q").html(questions[index]);
    $("#c").html(choices[index].toString());
    //And then,
    $("inout").keyup(function(){
        validateUserInput();  // validate user input
        // ask question passing another index
        askQuestion(index + 1); 
    });
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/quzet/1/edit)

So, there you see. `On` `input` `change`, fire an anonymous function, that `validates user input` and `ask`s another `question`.

Hope that helps!